# conda update conda not working due to Windows Program Files permissions

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I installed Anaconda for Python 2.7 for all users on my Windows 10 machine. When I try to update it via `conda update conda` I get the following error:

```
# You don't appear to have the necessary permissions to update packages
# into the install area 'C:\Program Files\Anaconda2'.
# However you can clone this environment into your home directory and
# then make changes to it.
# This may be done using the command:
#
# $ conda create -n my_root --clone=C:\Program Files\Anaconda2
```

Yet when I try to clone it into my home directory, I get the error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda2\\pkgs\\menuinst-1.4.1-py27_0.tmp'
```

Is there a way to solve this? I've been Googling but haven't found a clear solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to the start manual, find Anaconda Command Prompt. Right click on the icon and run it as an administrator (if you are). Then do the conda update as usual.

Comment: Why would it need this if it's installed for one user only?

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I installed Anaconda for myself only (instead of all users) and this solved the problem. Conversely, you can install Anaconda for all users and change the installation directory from 'Program Files' to your home directory and that should work. Quite a pain.

Comment: This is the default Windows behavior for all of its protected directories. Yes, it is a pain, but it is there for your protection. You can also install Anaconda for all users into a directory that doesn't require administrator permission to write, such as `C:\Anaconda`

Comment: @darthbith  This fix ( installing directly under C drive ) you found working with windows 7 or windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

Same error i got. Run windows powershell as adminstrator and run the command it will execute.